# CodeRush - Do That Suggested Fix - (shortcuts)

Tags: c#, vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts, coderush

What is the keyboard shortcut to get CodeRush to do the #1 suggested fix for the situation?
Do I really have to hover over the problem long enough to get the ellipse to show up and then pick a choice?

Also is there a way to jump to the next problem area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DevExpress options (under DevExpress > Options), there's a "IDE" section and a "shortcuts" subsection.

In there, you probably already have a keyboard shortcut defined for in the "Refactor" category for the "Refactor" command - that keyboard shortcut would bring up that selection box, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will then select the first option in that dialog box, by default.

Comment: I was really thinking about buying CodeRush and Refactor Pro but are they supposed to be this slow? and it seems to have broken my intellisense. I was loving the string refactor capabilities but it is really slowing me down today.

Comment: well, either Resharper or Coderush/Refactor will slow things down a bit - but at the same time, they increase your productivity - it's a trade-off, as always, speed vs. power/productivity. What's more important to you?

Comment: but everytime a type a character there is enough of a delay to be very annoying. And the broken intellisense is not great. Do I need a Quad, i5, or i7 to run this thing. I'm currently on a single chip at work.

Comment: No, that's definitely not normal - I feel some delay once in a while - most notably when loading large solutions. I run just fine on a Pentium D with 3.0 GHz and 4 GB of RAM. Definitely no slowdown when typing, and intellisense works just fine.

Comment: I recently found a strange edge case that cause one of my solutions on one of my machines to appear to cause CodeRush to perform very badly. I'm still not sure whta ultimately caused it, but in my case uninstalling StyleCop seems to fix it. see http://rorybecker.blogspot.com/2010/02/improve-speed-of-coderush-edgecase.html

Answer (score 2):

If you notice a delay contact support@devexpress.com and send some details to help us reproduce. Also, CodeRush doesn't interfere with Intellisense, but uninstalling *other* third-party IDE tools has been known to suppress Intellisense and this may be what happened to you. Try this: Open up the Visual Studio Tools menu then Text Editor and then C#. On that options page you will need to recheck "Auto list members" and "Parameter information" to get Intellisense reenabled.